# Does Twitter has a static page for OAuth redirects?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm developing a desktop application which is supposed to allow users to login via Twitter.
There seems to be 2 ways to do so, that differ in a way oauth_verifier is returned to the application. 
The first one is for web applications and `oauth_verifier` is returned as a url query parameter when redirecting user back to `redirect_url`.
The second one is using a PIN displayed to the user, which user enters to the app.

Now Facebook, for example, has a page `facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` , where FB can redirect a user with `ouath_verifier` as a query param (e.g. `facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?code=<token>`. Then I can read that param back from the browser's location field (I'm using an embedded browser).

So, is such a workflow possible with Twitter? Does it have a static page, where it can redirect user with `oauth_verifier` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find such a page in Twitter's API docs, so I ended up using the main page `twitter.com` for the redirect. Everything works fine.